# erlang maps key pattern match

Tags: erlang, maps, match

I am newer to erlang, I have a map like #{"a/.+":"v1", "b/c/.+": "v2"}

I want to get value by input key like "a/d" to match "a/.+" and get "v1".

It easy to pattern when key is exactly and input key is regex, how can I implement it.

Answer (score 2):

For this case, you **don't** have to use `map`. The idea is to use regex to find which key match with the input, and then return the mapped value.
The **un-optimized** version is using `re:run/2` without compiling the pattern.

```
L1 = [{"a/.+", "v1"}, {"b/c/.+", "v2"}],
LResult1 = lists:foldl(fun({K, V}, ListIn) ->  
            Match = re:run("a/d", K),
            case Match of
                nomatch -> ListIn;
                      _ -> ListIn ++ [{K, V}]
            end
        end,
        [],
        L1
        ),
case LResult1 of
    [] -> 
        no_matching_rule;
     _ -> 
        Hd1 = hd(LResult1),
        {K1, V1} = Hd1,
        V1
end.
```

The **optimized** version can be achieved by compiling the regex pattern once before using them.

```
{ok, Mp1} = re:compile("a/.+"),
{ok, Mp2} = re:compile("b/c/.+"),
L2 = [{Mp1, "v1"}, {Mp2, "v2"}],
LResult2 = lists:foldl(fun({K, V}, ListIn) ->  
            Match = re:run("a/d", K),
            case Match of
                nomatch -> ListIn;
                      _ -> ListIn ++ [{K, V}]
            end
        end,
        [],
        L2
        ),
case LResult2 of
    [] -> 
        no_matching_rule;
     _ -> 
        Hd2 = hd(LResult2),
        {K2, V2} = Hd2,
        V2
end.
```

Pasting any of above codes in Erlang shell will yield `"v1"`.

Above code assumes that one input can have multiple matched pattern, but only the first one will be printed as output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the keys in the map that match your string, you will need to iterate over the whole map:

a.erl:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

find(String, Map) ->
    MyMatchFun = fun (RegexKey, Val, Acc) -> 
                         case re:run(String, RegexKey) of
                             nomatch -> Acc;
                             {match, _} -> [Val | Acc]
                         end
                 end,
    maps:fold(MyMatchFun, _Acc=[], Map).
```

In the shell:

```
34> c(a).              
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

35> Map.
#{"a/.+" => "v1","a/b/.+" => "v3","b/c/.+" => "v2"}

36> a:find("a/d", Map).
["v1"]

36> a:find("b/c/dd", Map).
["v2"]

38> a:find("a/b/cc", Map).
["v3","v1"]
```

If there is only one key in the map that will match your string, then you can stop iterating over the map as soon as you find a match:

a.erl:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

find(String, Map) ->
    I = maps:iterator(Map),
    match_for(String, I).

match_for(String, I) ->
    case maps:next(I) of 
        none ->  %% then you have reached the end of the Map
            no_keys_in_map_matched_string;

        {RegExKey, Val, NewI} ->
            case re:run(String, RegExKey) of
                nomatch -> match_for(String, NewI);  %% continue iterating over the Map looking for a match
                {match, _} -> Val   %% found a match, so return the associated value
            end
    end.
```

In the shell:

```
27> c(a).                
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

28> Map = #{"a/.+" => "v1", "b/c/.+" => "v2"}.

29> a:find("a/d", Map).                                         
"v1"

30> a:find("a/b/cc", Map).
"v1"

31> a:find("b/c/dd", Map).
"v2"

32> a:find("z", Map).     
no_keys_in_map_matched_string
```